# Else if statements in C

Tags: c

I am creating a calculator that takes the square feet of a yard and spits out a dollar amount for cost as well as an estimate on time and the number of people needed

Here's what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(void)
{
// Define float values
float sqft,min,bill;
//Get the yard size in square feet from the user and store it in variable sqft
printf("Please enter in the yard size in square feet\n");
scanf("%d", &sqft);
// Gets the sqft from keyboard and puts it in one of three catagories, if it's less than 0 display an error message, if greater than 0 but less than 500 perform that operation//
// if greater than 500 but less than 2000 performs that operations, and if graeter than 2000, performs that operation//
if(500 >= sqft || sqft > 0 )
{
    puts("The cost is $25, require 1 worker, and will take approximately 25 minutes.");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
else if(500 < sqft || sqft <= 2000)
{
    bill = sqft * 0.03 +10;
    min = 5+ 0.04 * sqft;
    printf("The cost is %2f, requires 2 workers, and will take approximately %i.\n", bill, min);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
else if(2000< sqft)
{
    bill = sqft * 0.025 + 20;
    min = 60+ 0.0133;
    printf("The cost is %2f, requires 3 workers, and will take apprxoimately %i.\n", bill, min);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
else;
{
    puts("Please enter a numerical value greater than 0");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

The issue is that whenever I run the program I only get a response for the first if statement, "The cost is $25 requires 1 worker, and will take approximately 25 minutes.

It gives me this response if the value is 0, 501, 20000 or even just random letters. I've been knocking away at this for a couple hours, anyone have a better idea for me? or am I just doing something stupid?

Edit: Per the suggetions below I made some changes namely

```
9. scanf("%f", &sqft);
12. if(500 >= sqft && sqft >0)
```

It's now working, but I find that when I enter 4,000 for the value my minutes to complete come back as negative numbers, is this an overflow issue?

Is there a way to extend the limit for this? I would like it to be somewhere in the 6 digits to accompany any theoretical yards.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `scanf`. Using `"%d"` with a pointer to `float` is incorrect.  And always check the return value to see whether the variables were actually set or not.

Comment: `else;`  **<<--** remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or)

```
if(500 >= sqft || sqft > 0 )
```

is always true if either of the conditions is true, so if `sqft` is greater than `0`, the first `printf` is always done.

```
if(500 >= sqft && sqft > 0 )
```

is true only if both conditions are true, so `sqft` needs to be greater than `0` and smaller or equal to `500`

And be sure to change the `scanf` from `%d` to `%f` to read a float instead of an integer, as well as the arguments to `printf`.

Also, just as a readability tip, the comparison is much more readable as

```
if ((sqft > 0) && (sqft <= 500))
```

Comment: Yes that worked!
I need it to show the minutes correctly too, now that I have it working it seems to display a negative number for the minutes after I go above a certain number, as an example entering in 4,000 will come up with a negative number for the time, but 3000 will come back as the correct time

Is there anything I can do for that?

Thanks again!

Comment: fix the problem with `sqft` being decalared as a float and scanf reading in an integer and see if that helps, as is, you will get undefined behavior

Comment: you also need to use `%f` when printing `min`

Answer (score 3):

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* declaring `sqft` as `float`, but then attempting

```
scanf("%d", &sqft);
```

The `%d` *format specifier* is for integer values, you will need to use `%f` to read a float. (but I would encourage you to use `double` instead of `float` going forward, and the `%lf` modifier)

You likewise invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your `printf` statements using `%i` for the `float` values as well. (you need the *long* modifier to read `double` values with `scanf`, but **not** to print them with `printf`, the `%f` *format specifier* for `printf` handles `double` by default. Spend time with both `man pages` -- it is well worth the time spent.)

You logic could use a little work. Most importantly, ALWAYS, ALWAYS, validate the **return** of `scanf` or you can have no confidence you are actually processing valid data from that point forward. You could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {   /* main is type 'int' */

    /* declare and initialize double values */
    double sqft = 0.0, min = 0.0, bill = 0.0;

    printf ("enter yard size [in square feet]: ");

    /* ALWAYS validate user input */
    if (scanf( "%lf", &sqft) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (sqft <= 0) {    /* less than or equal to zero */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: sqft must be greater than zero.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (sqft <= 500)    /* less than or equal to 500 */
        puts("The cost is $25, require 1 worker, and "
                "will take approximately 25 minutes.");
    else if (sqft <= 2000) {    /* less than or equal to 2000 */
        bill = sqft * 0.03 + 10;
        min = 5 + 0.04 * sqft;
        printf ("The cost is %.2f, requires 2 workers, and will "
                "take approximately %.2f.\n", bill, min);
    }
    else if (sqft > 2000) {     /* greater than 2000 */
        bill = sqft * 0.025 + 20;
        min = 60 + 0.0133;
        printf ("The cost is %.2f, requires 3 workers, and will "
                "take apprxoimately %.3f.\n", bill, min);
    }

/* only hold terminal open on windoze */
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    getchar();  /* use getchar() to hold terminal open on windoze   */
    getchar();  /* (2-requied as '\n' remains in stdin after scanf) */
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

That will insure you have a valid `sqft` before you attempt to use it later in your code.

(**note:** never using *floating-point* values (`float or double`) for currency, people get real mad when you start losing money to rounding errors)

Comment: Yea I noticed that one right after I posted this, I changed it to

    scanf("%2f, &sqft);